# Editing tags in bunch of MP3 files?

Tags: windows, editing, mp3, tags

I have a bunch of files whose filename looks like `"<Track> - <Title> - <Artist>.mp3"`.

I'd like to rewrite their MP3 Title tag to be `"<Track> - <Title>.mp3"` so that each song is displayed correctly on my elcheapo MP3 player.

Since I rarely edit MP3 files anyway, [MP3 Tag Tools](http://massid3lib.sourceforge.net/) 1.2 Build 008 from 2003 was good enough, but I can't figure out how to do this with this application.

I just tried [MP3Tag](http://www.mp3tag.de/en/s) 2.46, but couldn't figure out if it can do this (created a new Action, to no avail). I also tried [TagScanner](http://www.xdlab.ru/en/) 5.1.558, without success.

Does someone know of a good, free Windows application that can do this? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mp3tag can handle that. I'm supposing your ID3 tags are correctly set (no missing titles, no missing track, etc).

Being all set, go to Action -> New. Name it "Cheap Mp3 Player" or other name of your preference. Then, select "New" to add a new action. Select Action Type -> Format Value.

In "Field", select "Title". In "Format String", write `%track% - %title%`.

After that, call the action you created in your mp3 files. It works. I tested here.

(If your ID3 tags are all messed up, just come back so I can give other options in Mp3Tag as well).

Answer (score 0):

I've used [Tag & Rename](http://www.softpointer.com/tr.htm), works really well for my purposes.  It's not quite free, but it has a trial period.  I rarely pay for software programs, and I bought this one.

It has great features

- renaming files from ID3 tags
- auto populating ID3 tags from file names
- editing multiple MP3s at a time.

Answer (score 0):

Both iTunes and WMP have a function to "manage my library files" or something similar where they can folder structure the files in the library.  IIRC (it's been a while) WMP has an option as part of that where you can change the format so you can make it be `<Track>-<Title>` and WMP will set about reorganising your library and the file names itself.

EDIT: Just checked iTunes and it doesn't have a changeable option but the format it uses is `<Track>-<Title>`

Answer (score 0):

I have had great success with [Tagscanner](http://www.xdlab.ru/en/). It is the most powerful, but straightforward tool I've come across.

Comment: Thanks. I'll check it out the next time I need to batch-tag MP3's.