# How to batch edit the metadata of mp3s?

Tags: batch, mp3

I would like to edit the metadata of several mp3s at once (say Album, Artists etc.). What is a quick and easy way to do that? I have Windows, OS X and Ubuntu available, so I don't mind using any of these OSes, as long as it's easy and quick.

Comment: Did you try anything so far?

Comment: In Windows Explorer I tried to select all the mp3 -> properties -> edit the tags, but all of them are greyed out. I would expect that for the title field, for example, but I don't understand why the Album and Artist fields are also greyed out.

Comment: I suspect the file is read-only? Or you don't have permissions.

Comment: Do you mind using a software?

Comment: @Unnikrishnan, the OP clearly wants some software to do it automaticaly but has been clever enough to word his question to not ask it directly! :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Windows: What software do you recommend for editing MP3 ID3 tags?](http://superuser.com/questions/5065/windows-what-software-do-you-recommend-for-editing-mp3-id3-tags), [Editing tags in bunch of MP3 files?](http://superuser.com/questions/119602/editing-tags-in-bunch-of-mp3-files?rq=1)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think Mp3tag is the best for your need. It is a powerful and yet easy-to-use tool to edit metadata of common audio formats where it supports ID3v1, ID3v2.3, ID3v2.4, iTunes MP4, WMA, Vorbis Comments and APE Tags.

[More info here](http://www.mp3tag.de/en/)

Comment: You may want to include which OS is supported (I know the OP says any, but still, it may help others :) )

Answer (score 1):

I use mp3info on Linux. On the command line you can quickly update the tags, like 
mp3info -a "artist" -t "title" -l "album" -y year *file(s)*.